# How does multi-tenancy work in infinispan

Tags: caching, jboss, multi-tenant, infinispan

**How does multi-tenancy work?**

Multi-tenancy is achieved by namespacing. A single Infinispan cluster can have several named caches (attached to the same CacheManager), and different named caches can have duplicate keys. So this is, in effect, multi-tenancy for your key/value store.
[source](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/overview/overview.html#how_does_multi_tenancy_work)

does anyone have an idea/example on how to configure a cache to be multitenant?

I have already read the documentation but I didn't find an example to follow.

> ps: I am using infinispan in embedded mode

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration in Infinispan for multi-tenancy. The sentence explains how to achieve it: you use the cache name to distinguish the namespace.

For example, for a specific group of users, you can create caches with the name "group_a_<cache_name>". In addition, you can set up authentication ([documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/security/security.html#authorization))

Comment: thanks for your quick answer one more question is there a possibility to take control of default commends ( get and put ) caches to modify the key passed as an argument? ( if the solution is **the visitors** do you have any idea how to register a visitor? the doc is not very helpful )

Comment: what's your use case? We don't support changing keys during execution. it will have an unpredictable outcome and/or exceptions.

Comment: well the solution for multi-tenancy that I want to have is : 

every time I perform a put() cache there is a logic behind that is going to take control and modify the key passed in the put method to concat  It with a tenant ID.
same with the get() the key value is going to be concatenated with the Tenant ID before executing the action to get the correct value of the cache.

Comment: you can do that replacement before invoking cache.put or cache.get. Just wrap your class with your logic around the Cache instance.

Comment: so there is no way to have this solution with the available tools provided by infinispan or jcache ( visitors /interceptors )...

Comment: if you want to use a custom interceptor, check https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#custom_interceptors_chapter. It is still available but it will be removed in the future.